# Why the param name is $accessToken?

Tags: google-drive-api

Developers of the Drive SDK - or generally, the OAuth2.0 PHP client library!

In the apiClient.php there is a `setAccessToken` function:

```
  public function setAccessToken($accessToken) {
    if ($accessToken == null || 'null' == $accessToken) {
      $accessToken = null;
    }
    self::$auth->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }
```

The @param of this function is something like this:

```
{"access_token":"TOKEN", "refresh_token":"TOKEN", "token_type":"Bearer",
        "expires_in":3600, "id_token":"TOKEN", "created":1320790426}
```

Why you name this parameter **$accessToken** if the  access token is *just a part* of this JSON encoded string ??

It's very misleading i think.

When we go deeper and look at: `$auth->setAccessToken($accessToken);` in apiOAuth2.php
we see:

```
  public function setAccessToken($accessToken) {
    $accessToken = json_decode($accessToken, true);
    if ($accessToken == null) {
      throw new apiAuthException('Could not json decode the access token');
    }
    if (! isset($accessToken['access_token'])) {
      throw new apiAuthException("Invalid token format");
    }
    $this->accessToken = $accessToken;
  }
```

Look at the second **if**: `$accessToken['access_token']`. Whats the point of this? Access token inside an accessToken ?? :)

You should name the `$accessToken` parameter (the whole JSON string) of these functions to something else like `$credentials` or whatever because it's a little bit blurry... but tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Although a reasonable question, this is exactly the sort of thing that should be asked in a forum specific to the library you are asking about.

Comment: You will find better help asking the same question on the PHP Client Library [support forum](https://groups.google.com/group/google-api-php-client).

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments mention I would post this either on the Google APIs PHP client library form: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-api-php-client
Or file an issue on their issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/list

This will make sure that the engineers working on the PHP client library will be aware of this.

And you are right this makes perfect sense :)